# npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: node.js, npm

I did the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/nibtehaz/NORTH-app.git
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
npm install # which caused the following error
```

and got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did what was suggested, but it lead to another problem:

```
sudo apt install node-gyp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-gyp : Depends: libnode-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

What did I miss?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/899756/cant-install-npm-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: Unfortunately,I tried it but it did not work. I updated my question.

Comment: i had same problem, then i tried and worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057737/ubuntu-18-04-lts-server-npm-depends-node-gyp-0-10-9-but-it-is-not-going

Answer (score 29):

For Ubuntu 18.x and 20.04, here's what does it:

```sh
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs npm
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install curl
cd ~
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
node -v && npm -v
```

Comment: In some cases: node -v && npm -v

Comment: Apart from adding unnecessary yarn bits, this is the correct approach

Comment: This specifically installs Node 14. For other versions see https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall (the initial cleaning steps are still needed)

Comment: after some time, this one works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

If you face this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 do:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
sudo apt install npm
```

[Check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258870/ubuntu-20-04-should-i-downgrade-libssl1-1-to-libssl1-0-to-install-npm)

Comment: This is really quite a bad suggestion. You're suggesting people DOWNGRADE their version of libssl1.1 - resulting in the loss of security updates!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same thing, when I tried to install `nodejs` and `npm` in a buster-based docker container.
It seems that now, you need to install `yarn` which will take `npm` along.

The solution was `apt-get install nodejs yarn`.
Afterwards, the `npm` command worked.

Comment: This worked for me. Altough it seems, like nodjs with version 16.x includes npm anyway? The output was `## Run sudo apt-get install -y nodejs to install Node.js 16.x *and* npm` Might be that the installer simply ignored the `yarn` thingy.

Answer (score 0):

Install Node 18 and yarn on Ubuntu 22.04:

```bash
# Preinstallation
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs npm
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoremove

# Install node repo
wget -q https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x -O nodejs_setup_18.x.sh
sed -ri "/^exec_cmd 'apt-get update/ s/^/#/g" ./nodejs_setup_18.x.sh
sed -ri "s@(print_status 'Running \`apt-get update\` for you...')@\1\napt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist='sources.list.d/nodesource.list' -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts='-' -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup='0'@" ./nodejs_setup_18.x.sh
sudo bash ./nodejs_setup_18.x.sh

# Install node package
sudo apt-get install nodejs

# Install yarn repo
wget -q https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg -O- | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist='sources.list.d/yarn.list' -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts='-' -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup='0'

# Install yarn package
sudo apt-get install yarn
```